# Scoring a Item Based on Votes

Tags: voting-system

I am creating an item selection system that allows a group of people to vote on their favorite item by ranking it between 1 (no good / least favorite) to 5 (very good/favorite).

I received a bunch of votes and now I need to select one. One option is to sum their scores from all votes or, perhaps better, sum the square of their votes to favor items with very high votes.

One issue I've found is that some items have very high votes AND very low votes --- they are quite controversial!

I'm thinking to prefer items that are highly ranked AND non-controversial. To this end, I thought I would penalize controversial items by dividing by `(1+variance(item_votes)` so score for each item is

score(item) = `sum_squared(item_votes)/(1+variance(item_votes)`

Is there a superior, standard way to prefer uncontroversial items?

Comment: This is tangential, but FWIW you might want to have a non-reduced range scale if you're collecting more vote-like data in the future. Forcing people to use a 1-5 scale might hide some interesting variability as compared to a "choose a point on this line" approach.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you clarify what your exact question is? "prefer" is not defined.

Comment: @AdamO Thank you. My question is whether there is a standard mechanism or framework to penalize options that exhibit high scores but are "controversial" in the sense that they have high average and high variance. Presumably this would be a simple method to penalize bimodal distributions where people either love or hate the option and unimodal with wide variance. In this case, "prefer" means that when two items with the same average are compared, the item with less variance (or equivalent) would be selected.

Comment: @Steve why would you penalize anything? If half the people like it absolutely and half the people hate it absolutely, then a 50% average is an appropriate rating unless you can formalize other metrics.

Comment: @AdamO Because want the chosen item to be the one with the highest average score but also one that isn't particularly offensive to a percentage of the population.